# Can't use ThreadPoolExecutor in the right way when a function produces a single link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I've created a script using concurrent.futures library to do multithreading in order to execute the script faster. If the first function `get_content_url()` within the script produced multiple links, the current implementation would work. However, as the first function is producing a single link, I don't understand how to use concurrent.futures in such cases.

To let you understand what the first function is doing - when I supply ids from a csv file to this function `get_content_url()`, it generates a single link by using the token collected from json response.

> How can I apply `concurrent.futures` within the script in the right way to make the execution faster?

I've tried with:

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_link = "https://www.some_website.com/{}"
target_link = "https://www.some_website.com/{}"

def get_content_url(item_id):
    r = requests.get(base_link.format(item_id['id']))
    token = r.json()['token']
    content_url = target_link.format(token)
    yield content_url

def get_content(target_link):
    r = requests.get(target_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    try:
        title = soup.select_one("h1#maintitle").get_text(strip=True)
    except Exception: title = ""
    print(title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("IDS.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            for _id in reader:
                future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_content,item): item for item in get_content_url(_id)}
                concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit hard to reproduce, since I don't know what's inside the `IDS.csv` and a valid url case is missing in your question but here's something to play with:

```
import csv
import random

import requests
import concurrent.futures
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_link = "https://www.some_website.com/{}"
target_link = "https://www.some_website.com/{}"


def get_content_url(item_id):
    url = base_link.format(item_id)
    print(f"Requesting {url}...")
    token = requests.get(url).json()['token']
    return target_link.format(token)


def get_content(item_id):
    url = get_content_url(item_id)
    print(f"Fetching {url}...")
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    try:
        title = soup.select_one("h1#maintitle").get_text(strip=True)
        return title
    except Exception as exc:
        return exc


def write_fake_ids():
    fake_ids = [
        {"item": "sample_item", "item_id": _} for _ in 
        random.sample(range(1000, 10001), 1000)
    ]
    with open("IDS.csv", "w") as output:
        w = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fake_ids[0].keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(fake_ids)


def get_ids():
    with open("IDS.csv") as csv_file:
        ids = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        yield from (id_ for id_ in ids)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        future_to_url = {
            executor.submit(get_content, id_['item_id']): id_ for id_ in get_ids()
        }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            print(future.result())
```

I'm mocking the .csv file with `write_fake_ids()`. You can ignore it or remove it, it doesn't get called anywhere in the code.

Comment: Although I didn't test your script yet, I suppose it is more or less doing something like [this](https://pastebin.com/WL01Nwdg). I didn't post this only because i thought there is any better way. Thanks.